# Compile css with Ruby Sass, via php

Tags: php, ruby, sass

I'm currently using https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass

With every page load, I am doing the following:

1. get list of scss files
2. check if any of them are newer than the last time, if so:
3. make an @import list and `file_put_contents($importlist)`
4. instantiate PhpSass, give it the $importlist path: `$css = $sass->toCss(pathtoImporterSass);`
5. write the css file:  `file_put_contents($pathtocachefile, $css);`
6. and then, serve the css.

So, I am wondering how to do step 4 via Ruby, instead of phpSass.  PhpSass is working ok, but it has some limitations (doesnt understand all of sass functions, strips `!important`, etc )

Comment: Just so you know there is also a mod_sass if you are an apache user.

Comment: I am.  Cant find any documentation for mod_sass, though, do you know of any?

Comment: You have to compile it your self. I tried to do it on Ubuntu 12.04 and was able to do it. I used this: https://github.com/kjdev/apache-mod-sass it has instructions below on how to compile.